# How do you create / copy image to multiple devices of the same type?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, images, kiosk-mode

I work at a startup and we have a bit of a conundrum.

We need to install the same image on hundreds of devices.

The things we have to do:

- Put the device in kiosk mode (either through system settings or an app)
- Set some system settings (Internet, Roaming, GPS)
- Install an App

Is there a way to do this by copying a complete image of a device and put it on other devices? Can this be done with releatively little interactivty by the developer?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this can be automated using ADB scripts.

`adb install app.apk` will install `app.apk`.

System settings can be changed via `adb` also (see here for more details: http://andrejfernandes.pt/?p=171).

Heck, `adb input` can even automate entire user interfaces!

If you really, really need to have the phones be exact mirrors and all devices have a custom recovery installed, then you can reboot into recovery on all devices with `adb reboot recovery`. Then get an image of the data and internal SD partition using `dd` in the recovery shell. Finally, push the images out onto the rest of the devices via `adb push` and `dd` them back onto their respective partitions.